# How to disable location sending to Xtify?

Tags: push-notification, xtify

There is a requirement where user want to control his location sharing (or not sharing) from custom setting screen inside the application.
But as per my understanding `Xtify` SDK keeps on sending location always to `Xtify` if user has initially accepted to share location at the time of install.

Can we control the location sending option to `Xtify` by SDK function?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sending of location. Use:

```
XtifyLocation.disableRepetitiveLocUpdate(getApplicationContext());
```

on Android, and

```
[[XLappMgr get] updateLocationRequiredFlag:NO];
```

on iOS to disable sending up location.